# Routes don't work in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters, routes

I have two routes `/emails` and `/eamils/:id`:

```
var createRouter = function() {
  var router = express.Router();

  router.route('/emails/:id').get((req, res) => {
    console.log('get=>/emails/id');
  });

  router.route('/emails').get((req, res) => {
    console.log('get> /emails');
  });

  return router;
}
```

Whenever next request is sent the second handler gets called:

```
GET http://localhost:4000/rest-api/emails/?id=59
```

The first one which takes `id` parameter never works. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide more info? What does _never work_ mean? How do you send requests?

Comment: You know you can do .get("/emails",(req,res)=>...)

Comment: Did you mean to forget the closing single quote after  `console.log('get> /emails);`?  Just want to make sure this isn't a really simple mistype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct url should be:

```
http://localhost:4000/rest-api/emails/59
```

and not:

```
http://localhost:4000/rest-api/emails/?id=59
```

here id is query param.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
http://localhost:4000/rest-api/emails/59
```

Query parameters don't count.

Answer (score 1):

`http://localhost:400/rest-api/emails/59` is correct. You are using **params** and not **queries**.

If you want to use **queries** their usage is like this after `?` sign.

`http://localhost:400/rest-api/emails?id=59`